# How to get FB User ID using Facebook Login Button in android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing an application in which I'm using `Facebook` log in button from SDK. I'm able to get `access_token` of the user but I want `userID` too. I have tried almost everything but was not successful.  I have used facebook tutorial for achieving that. Here is the link: [Facebook Login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/)

Please help me in getting `userID` from the same login button.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After successful login, you need to call following code. You can get the logged-in user details with id in response.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me", null);
com.facebook.Response response = Request.executeAndWait(request)
```

Comment: Even easier, the Request class has a newMeRequest helper method: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newMeRequest%28Session,%20GraphUserCallback%29

Answer (score 11):

Use the getId method of FB Profile class( Facebook SDK 4.0).

```
  Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
  System.out.println(profile.getFirstName());
  System.out.println(profile.getId());
```

Answer (score 8):

```
loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
```

Comment: for some reason `Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();` and `profile.getUserId()` is not working with current sdk. So, this is the best solution currently.

Answer (score 4):

You should be used new facebook sdk 3.0 and

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) {
            // Request user data and show the results
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Display the parsed user info
                        Log.v(TAG, "Response : " + response);
                        Log.v(TAG, "UserID : " + user.getId());
                        Log.v(TAG, "User FirstName : " + user.getFirstName());

                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: where will we start the activity ? You shared what we should do at the end, but could you please show me where to start intent?

Comment: `executeMeRequestAsync` is deprecated. Use `newMeRequest` instead

Answer (score 3):

Based on answer from @Ketan Mehta (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17397931/624109) that uses a deprecated API, you should use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (Session.getActiveSession().isOpened())
    {
        // Request user data and show the results
        Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new GraphUserCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
            {
                if (null != user)
                {
                    // Display the parsed user info
                    Log.v(TAG, "Response : " + response);
                    Log.v(TAG, "UserID : " + user.getId());
                    Log.v(TAG, "User FirstName : " + user.getFirstName());

                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As these all answers are for older SDK , for SDK 4.0 here is the code

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new    FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            Log.d("facebook",profile.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.d("facebook","failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.d("facebook","failed");
        }
    });
```

i was searching for the same thing looks like the Session object is no more accessible so above is the new way to get user profile and user id.

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook graph API lets you make calls that return JSON, which you can parse in Android with a JSONObject like this below code.

```
JSONObject me = new JSONObject(fb.request("me"));
String id = me.getString("id");
```

Comment: #RajaReddy PolamReddy: how did you define the variable `fb`?  And are you referring to the 3.0 SDK (or 2.0 with the deprecated Facebook class)?

Comment: it's a old facebook sdk . that time it has Facebook class in the facebook sdk

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user ID with this code :

```
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
   'Welcome ' + response.name + '!' + "<br />"+
   'Your user ID is : ' + response.id;
```