# Getting user id for facebook

Tags: android, facebook, access-token, userid

I am working on an Android Application. A part of this application is to login on Facebook. I can get the access tokens.I am populating my database and want the Facebook user id to be the PID for each person on the database.

How do I extract the user id after logging in on Facebook through the android app?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The [following](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/fetch-user-data) is a tutorial on how to fetch data from Facebook after logging in using Facebook, it includes the **ID**, **Birthday**, **Username**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might help to those who are using or will use or implement JSON.
The Facebook Graph API lets us make calls and it returns JSON. This JSON can be parsed in android.
The way do it is:

```
JSONObject me = new JSONObject(fb.request("me"));
String id = me.getString("id");
```

CREDITS: [How to get FB User ID using Facebook Login Button in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568159/how-to-get-fb-user-id-using-facebook-login-button-in-android-application)